# ¿Cómo se nota el atributo de una relación con Pony ORM?

Tags: python, ponyorm

Estoy echándole un vistazo a Pony ORM y no consigo ver cómo notar el atributo asociado a una relación. Supongamos lo siguiente:

```
class Vehiculo(db.Entity):
    "Modela un vehículo"
    matricula = Required(str)
    #Otros atributos del vehículo.
    accidentes = Set(lambda: Accidente)

class Accidente(db.Entity):
   "Modela un accidente de tráfico"
   descripcion = Optional(str)
   lugar = Required(str)
   # Otros atributos más que caracterizan al accidente
   accidentados = Set(Vehiculo)
```

O sea una relación muchos a muchos. Ahora supongamos que como atributo de esa relación muchos a muchos quisiera incluir el attributo *culpable*, que determina si un determinado vehículo o no ha sido uno de los responsables del accidente. ¿Cómo hago esto?

Sé que en este caso, puedo resolverlo incluyendo el atributo *responsables* como una colección de *Vehiculos* en *Accidente*:

```
class Accidente(db.Entity):
    # [...]
    responsables = Set(Vehiculo)
```

pero no sé si en todos los casos hay una forma de evitar la creación de un atributo de la relación. Además, esto se podría prestar a inconsistencias en la base de datos (un vehículo que está en la colección de responsables, pero no en la de accidentados, por ejemplo).

Otra solución evidente es hacer explícita la entidad que resulta de la relación (y llamarla *Parte*, por ejemplo).

¿Alguna idea de si se pueden definir atributos para las relaciones? Yo no veo nada en la documentación.

Comment: Desconozco PonyORM, pero es práctica general con los ORMs evitar usar *relaciones n-m*. Lo de crear una nueva entidad llamada `Parte` sería la mejor solución.

Comment: Recién conozco de la existencia de PonyORM, en Django es posible controlar la tabla intermedia que se crea para las relaciones de muchos a muchos, en este caso podría llamarse `VehiculoAccidente`, si es posible hacer esto en PonyORM, entonces esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo, luego tu agregarías los detalles que consideres necesarios en la tabla intermedia, como el campo `culpable` por ejemplo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SE ESTA TRADUCIENDO**

> PonyORM author is here.  Sorry, I don't speak Spanish, hope you can
>   read this and may be somebody can translate it to Spanish ;)

El autor de `PonyORM` esta aquí. Lo siento, no hablo español, espero que usted puede leer esto y puede que alguien pueda traducirlo al español ;)

> In the situation that you've described it would be better to use an
>   intermediate entity.

En la situación que usted ha descrito que sería mejor utilizar una entidad intermedia.

> Here is an example of using such an entity. At first we need to do the
>   necessary imports and define a database object:

He aquí un ejemplo del uso de tal entidad `entity`. En un primer lugar tenemos que hacer las importaciones necesarias y definir un objeto de base de datos `database object`:

```
from pony.orm import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
db = Database('sqlite', ':memory:')
```

> Now we can define four entities: `Car`, `Accident`, `AccidentRole` and
>   `Person`. The first entity is the `Car`:

Ahora podemos definir cuatro entidades: `Car`, `Accident`, `AccidentRole` y`Person`. La primera entidad es `Car`:

```
class Car(db.Entity):
    number = Required(str, unique=True)
    current_owner = Optional(lambda: Person)
    accident_roles = Set(lambda: AccidentRole)
```

> This entity has the `current_owner` attribute which refers to a
>   `Person`. I call this attribute `current_owner`, because during its
>   lifetime a car can have a number of owners.

Esta entidad tiene el atributo `current_owner` que se refiere a un`Person`
Yo llamo a este atributo `current_owner`, debido a que durante su tiempo de vida de un coche puede tener un número de propietarios.

> The next attribute is `accident_roles`. It is a relation to an
>   intermediate entity `AccidentRoles` which keeps additional attributes
>   for a logical relation between `Car` and `Accident`.

El siguiente atributo es `accident_roles`. Se trata de una relación con una entidad intermedia `AccidentRoles` que mantiene atributos adicionales para una relación lógica entre `Car` y `Accident`.

> The following entity describes accident itself:

La siguiente entidad describe accidente en sí mismo:

```
class Accident(db.Entity):
    place = Required(str)
    time = Required(datetime)
    participants = Set(lambda: AccidentRole)
```

> The `particiapnts` relation is linked with the following intermediate
>   entity:

La relación `participants` está vinculada `linked` con la siguiente entidad intermedia:

```
class AccidentRole(db.Entity):
    car = Required(lambda: Car)
    accident = Required(lambda: Accident)
    PrimaryKey(car, accident)  # composite primary key
    responsible = Required(bool, default=False)
    driver = Required(lambda: Person)
    owner = Required(lambda: Person)
```

> This entity has a composite primary key which consists of two
>   attributes: `car` and `accident`. This way we avoid a situation when
>   the same car has multiple relations with the same `Accident` object.

Esta entidad tiene una clave primaria compuesta que consta de dos atributos: `car` y `accident`. De esta manera evitar una situación en la que el mismo `car` tenga múltiples relaciones con el mismo objeto `Accident`.

> This entity has two additional relations with the Person entity -
>   `driver` and `owner`. We need this because the owner can be changed
>   over time, and we need to know who was the owner at the moment of the
>   accident. Also the driver and the owner could be separate persons.

Esta entidad tiene dos relaciones adicionales con la entidad Persona - `driver` y `owner`. Necesitamos esto porque el propietario puede cambiar con el tiempo, y necesitamos saber quién era el propietario en el momento del accidente.También el conductor y el propietario podrían ser personas separadas.

> The last entity in our example is a `Person`. The person is related to
>   cars which this person currently owns. Also we define two reverse
>   attributes `driver_in_accidents` and `car_owner_in_accidents`. This is
>   because in Pony we always specify a relationship by its both ends.

La última entidad en nuestro ejemplo es `Person`. La persona se relaciona con coches que actualmente posee esta persona. También se definen dos atributos inversos `driver_in_accidents` y `car_owner_in_accidents`. Esto es porque en Pony siempre especificar una relación por sus dos extremos.

```
class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    cars = Set(lambda: Car)
    driver_in_accidents = Set(lambda: AccidentRole, reverse='driver')
    car_owner_in_accidents = Set(lambda: AccidentRole, reverse='owner')
```

> Here you can see the visual diagram of our example:

Aquí usted puede ver el diagrama visual de nuestro ejemplo:

https://editor.ponyorm.com/user/kozlovsky/Accidents1#

> Now we can generate database tables and populate the data. At first we
>   can define some persons and their cars:

Ahora podemos generar tablas de bases de datos y rellenar los datos. En un primer momento podemos definir algunas personas `persons` y sus coches `car`:

```
with db_session:
    santiago = Person(name='Santiago Garcia')
    car1 = Car(number='A-0849-CS', current_owner=santiago)
    car2 = Car(number='GI-8165-BL', current_owner=santiago)

    mateo = Person(name='Mateo Fernandez')
    car3 = Car(number='M-4775-ZX', current_owner=mateo)

    diego = Person(name='Diego Lopez')
    car4 = Car(number='5000-DJP', current_owner=diego)

    leonardo = Person(name='Leonardo Martinez')
    car5 = Car(number='7137-CHW', current_owner=leonardo)
```

> Now we can define some accidents. The first accident has two
>   participants, Santiago and Mateo. Santiago was responsible for the
>   accident. Mateo managed `car4`, which was later sold to Diego:

Ahora podemos definir algunos accidentes. El primer accidente tiene dos participantes, Santiago y Mateo. Santiago era el responsable del accidente. Mateo manejaba `car4`, que fue vendido posteriormente a Diego:

```
    a1 = Accident(place='Madrid', time=datetime(2008, 1, 1, 12, 00))
    a1.participants.create(car=car1, driver=santiago, owner=santiago, responsible=True)
    a1.participants.create(car=car4, driver=mateo, owner=mateo)
```

> The second accident has two participants, Santiago and Diego. Diego
>   managed the same `car4` which participate in a previous accident:

El segundo accidente tiene dos participantes, Santiago y Diego. Diego maneja el mismo `car4` que participo en un accidente anterior:

```
    a2 = Accident(place='Sevilla', time=datetime(2011, 5, 31, 15, 30))
    a2.participants.create(car=car2, driver=santiago, owner=santiago, responsible=True)
    a2.participants.create(car=car4, driver=diego, owner=diego)
```

> The third accident has three participants. The driver responsible for
>   the accident was Leonardo, who managed the car belonging to Diego:

El tercer accidente tiene tres participantes. El conductor responsable del accidente fue Leonardo, que manejaba el coche que pertenece a Diego:

```
    a3 = Accident(place='Granada', time=datetime(2015, 11, 1, 16, 00))
    a3.participants.create(car=car4, driver=leonardo, owner=diego, responsible=True)
    a3.participants.create(car=car1, driver=santiago, owner=santiago)
    a3.participants.create(car=car3, driver=mateo, owner=mateo)
```

---

> Now after we populated the database we can look at some useful
>   queries:
>
> Cars which were not in any accident

Ahora, después de poblar la base de datos podemos ver algunas consultas útiles:

**Coches que no estaban en cualquier accidente**

```python
select(c for c in Car if not c.accident_roles).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "c"."id", "c"."number", "c"."current_owner"
FROM "Car" "c"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "AccidentRole" "accidentrole-1"
    WHERE "c"."id" = "accidentrole-1"."car"
    )
```

Result:

```
id|number  |current_owner
--+--------+-------------
5 |7137-CHW|Person[4]
```

> Last year's accidents

**Accidentes del año pasado**

```python
select((role.car, role.accident.time, role.driver, role.owner)
       for role in AccidentRole
       if role.accident.time >= datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "role"."car", "accident-1"."time", "role"."driver", "role"."owner"
FROM "AccidentRole" "role", "Accident" "accident-1"
WHERE "accident-1"."time" >= ?
  AND "role"."accident" = "accident-1"."id"
```

Result:

```
role.car|role.accident.time |role.driver|role.owner
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------
Car[1]  |2015-11-01 16:00:00|Person[1]  |Person[1] 
Car[3]  |2015-11-01 16:00:00|Person[2]  |Person[2] 
Car[4]  |2015-11-01 16:00:00|Person[4]  |Person[3]
```

> Cars which was in last year's accidents

**Coches que se encontraba en los accidentes del año pasado**

```python
select(role.car for role in AccidentRole
       if role.accident.time >= datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "car-1"."id", "car-1"."number", "car-1"."current_owner"
FROM "AccidentRole" "role", "Accident" "accident-1", "Car" "car-1"
WHERE "accident-1"."time" >= ?
  AND "role"."accident" = "accident-1"."id"
  AND "role"."car" = "car-1"."id"
```

Result:

```
id|number   |current_owner
--+---------+-------------
1 |A-0849-CS|Person[1]    
3 |M-4775-ZX|Person[2]    
4 |5000-DJP |Person[3]
```

> Cars which was in several accidents

**Coches que estaba en varios accidentes**

```python
select(c for c in Car if count(c.accident_roles) > 1).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "c"."id"
FROM "Car" "c"
  LEFT JOIN "AccidentRole" "accidentrole-1"
    ON "c"."id" = "accidentrole-1"."car"
GROUP BY "c"."id"
HAVING COUNT("accidentrole-1"."ROWID") > 1
```

Result:

```
id|number   |current_owner
--+---------+-------------
1 |A-0849-CS|Person[1]    
4 |5000-DJP |Person[3]
```

> Drivers who were responsible for several accidents

**Los conductores que eran responsables de varios accidentes**

```python
select(role.driver for role in AccidentRole if role.responsible and count() > 1).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "role"."driver"
FROM "AccidentRole" "role"
WHERE "role"."responsible"
GROUP BY "role"."driver"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
id|name           
--+---------------
1 |Santiago Garcia
```

> There I want to give some additional explanation. When some aggregate
>   function is used inside query and this function is not applied to a
>   collection, Pony adds `GROUP BY` section which includes all
>   non-grouped expressions from the `SELECT` list. In this query we group
>   result by driver. If an aggregated expression is used to filtering, it
>   goes to the `HAVING` section of the query, whereas non-grouped
>   expressions goes to the `WHERE` section. `count()` function without
>   arguments translated to `COUNT(*)`

Ya está. Quiero dar alguna explicación adicional.Cuando algunos `aggregate function` se utiliza dentro de consulta y esta función no se aplica a una colección, Pony adds `GROUP BY` la sección que incluye todas las expresiones no agrupadas de la lista `SELECT`. En este grupo de resultados de consulta por el conductor.Si se agrega una expresión es usada para filtrar, se va a la `HAVING` sección de la consulta, mientras `non-grouped` va a la `WHERE` section. `count()` función sin argumentos trasladado a `COUNT(*)`

> Accidents with more than two cars

**Accidentes con más de dos coches**

```python
select(a for a in Accident if count(a.participants) > 2).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "a"."id"
FROM "Accident" "a"
  LEFT JOIN "AccidentRole" "accidentrole-1"
    ON "a"."id" = "accidentrole-1"."accident"
GROUP BY "a"."id"
HAVING COUNT("accidentrole-1"."ROWID") > 2
```

Result:

```
id|place  |time               
--+-------+-------------------
3 |Granada|2015-11-01 16:00:00
```

> Drivers who never were in any accident

**Los conductores que nunca estuvieron en un accidente**

```python
select(p for p in Person if not p.driver_in_accidents).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."name"
FROM "Person" "p"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "AccidentRole" "accidentrole-1"
    WHERE "p"."id" = "accidentrole-1"."driver"
    )
```

Result:

```
id|name
--+----
```

> Drivers who were never responsible for any accident

**Los conductores que no eran responsables de cualquier accidente**

```python
select(p for p in Person if not exists(
    role for role in p.driver_in_accidents if role.responsible)
).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."name"
FROM "Person" "p"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "AccidentRole" "role"
    WHERE "p"."id" = "role"."driver"
      AND "role"."responsible"
    )
```

Result:

```
id|name           
--+---------------
2 |Mateo Fernandez
3 |Diego Lopez
```

> Drivers who were responsible in the accident where he was not the
>   owner of the car

**Los conductores que eran responsables en el accidente en el que no era el propietario del coche**

```python
select(role.driver for role in AccidentRole
       if role.responsible and role.driver != role.owner
).show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "person-1"."id", "person-1"."name"
FROM "AccidentRole" "role", "Person" "person-1"
WHERE "role"."responsible"
  AND "role"."driver" <> "role"."owner"
  AND "role"."driver" = "person-1"."id"
```

Result:

```
id|name             
--+-----------------
4 |Leonardo Martinez
```

> Persons who were in some accidents in Madrid

**Las personas que se encontraban en algunos accidentes en Madrid**

```python
select(role.driver for role in AccidentRole if role.accident.place == 'Madrid').show()
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "person-1"."id", "person-1"."name"
FROM "AccidentRole" "role", "Accident" "accident-1", "Person" "person-1"
WHERE "accident-1"."place" = 'Madrid'
  AND "role"."accident" = "accident-1"."id"
  AND "role"."driver" = "person-1"."id"
```

Result:

```
id|name           
--+---------------
1 |Santiago Garcia
2 |Mateo Fernandez
```

> Hope that helps

Espero que le ayude

Comment: Hi, is my solution valid? I did something similar to Django's intermediate table approach. I just read about Pony a few days ago but that seems to be working

Comment: @César your solution looks interesting, but currently is unsupported by Pony. Actually it is a bug that the Pony did not raise exception here. Internally Pony maintain many-to-many relationships and entities differently, so I suspect that such definition can lead to consistency errors. But maybe in the future we can implement the suggested syntax too :)

Comment: @Alexander How kind of you! Thanks for your reply. Cesar's solution it's cool and elegant. I hope we can implementent in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Buscando un poco en la documentación de PonyORM, en la sección [Mapping customization](https://docs.ponyorm.com/entities.html#mapping-customization), creo que es posible agregar una columna adicional en la tabla intermedia en las relaciones de muchos a muchos:

> If you need to set the column names for the intermediate table for many-to-many relationship, you should specify the option column or columns for the Set attributes.

Y se muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class Student(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    courses = Set("Course", table="Study_Plans", columns=["course", "semester"])

class Course(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    semester = Required(int)
    students = Set(Student, column="student_id")
    PrimaryKey(name, semester)
```

PonyORM por defecto crea el nombre de las tablas intermedias con el nombre de las entidades ordenados alfabéticamente, en este caso la tabla por defecto se llamaría `Course_Student`, pero como estamos pasándole el parámetro `table` se sobreescribe el nombre a `Study_Plans`. Los campos que se crearán tomados de los parámetros `columns` y `column` serían: `student_id`, `course` y `semester`.

Si se ejecuta el script te crea la siguiente estructura de tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE "Course" (
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "semester" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("name", "semester")
)

CREATE TABLE "Student" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "Study_Plans" (
  "course" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "semester" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "student_id" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Student" ("id"),
  PRIMARY KEY ("course", "semester", "student_id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("course", "semester") REFERENCES "Course" ("name", "semester")
)
```

Aunque aun no termino de entenderlo del todo, es decir, ¿para que necesitarías duplicar el campo en la tabla intermedia y en una de las otras tablas? No tiene mucho sentido para mi.

### Posible solución

Haciendo algunas pruebas adicionales, me he dado cuenta que incluso es posible definir la tabla intermedia (algo similar a lo que mencionaba en mi comentario), por lo que creo que lo mas cercano a lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```
from pony.orm import *

db = Database("sqlite", ":memory:")

class Vehiculo(db.Entity):
    matricula = Required(str)
    accidentes = Set('Accidente', table='Parte')

class Accidente(db.Entity):
   descripcion = Optional(str)
   lugar = Required(str)
   accidentados = Set('Vehiculo')

class Parte(db.Entity):
    responsable = Required(bool)

sql_debug(True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Le estoy indicando que el nombre de la tabla intermedia sea `Parte` y esta tabla también la estoy definiendo solo con el campo adicional que necesitas. Si ejecuto el script, el resultado en SQL es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE "Accidente" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "descripcion" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "lugar" TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "Vehiculo" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "matricula" TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "Parte" (
  "accidente" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Accidente" ("id"),
  "vehiculo" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Vehiculo" ("id"),
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "responsable" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("accidente", "vehiculo")
)
```

Bueno, hoy aprendí algo de PonyORM, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Efectivamente, tu posibles solución es la solución que busco (lo primero que iindicas ya lo había visto). Creo lo que se te ha ocurrido intentar,no está en la documentación: yo por lo menos no lo he visto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JoséMiguelSA si, se me ocurrió hacer lo mismo que hago en el ORM de Django y funciona perfecto. De nada :)